# Use and implementation of the binary `is` operator with simple types in D. (DLang)

Tags: pointers, d, comparison-operators

In D, is there any difference between the binary `is` operator in the case

```d
void * p;
if ( p is null ) { }       // #1
```

using pointers, versus simply either

```d
if  ( ! p ) { }            // #2a
```

or

```d
if ( p == null ) { }       // #2b
```

without the is operator?  (DLang)

(I'm restricting this to simple scalar types, no aggregates or complex types. I am aware that with classes `is` simply compares their addresses, iirc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With type `void*`, like other plain pointers, there's no difference. There's also no difference with `int`, but there are differences with other types, including `float`, arrays (including strings), structs, and classes.

I suggest you always write what you mean with any type, so if you change the type later it will be ok. Use `is` for seeing if two references are the same. Use `==` for seeing if contents are the same. Avoid `!p`, unless perhaps `p` is known to be a plain `bool` type, since it has the most surprising behavior (it does `cast(bool)` which can call an overloaded `opCast!bool` on structs and classes, and does `.ptr !is null` on arrays, which opens the joy of null vs zero length arrays). Better to just say what you mean and keep the code explicitly readable and resilient against refactorings.